# Sort an Array using Bubble sort, Error- required: variable, found: value

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort an array using **Bubble sort**, but it won't work. It says 'required: variable, found: value'

> Array.java:143: error: unexpected type 
>                       temp.get(d) = temp.get(d+1);
>                              
>  ^
>     
> required: variable
>     found:    value
>   
>   Array.java:144: error: unexpected type 
>                       temp.get(d+1) = swap;
>                              
>  ^
>     required: variable
>     found:    value

So the Main is given, and all I need to do is write this Bubble sort function



This is what I wrote

```
public static void bubbleSort(Array<Integer> lista){
boolean swapped;
    Array<Integer> temp;
    int n;

    n= temp.size;

    int swap;

     for (int c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
            if (temp.get(d) > temp.get(d+1))
            {
                swap = temp.get(d);
                temp.get(d) = temp.get(d+1);
                temp.get(d+1) = swap;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

And here's the Main that was given

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    String s = stdin.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(s);
    Array<Integer> niza =new Array<Integer>(N);
    bubbleSort(niza);

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        s = stdin.readLine();
        niza.set(i, Integer.parseInt(s));
    }

    System.out.println(brojDoProsek(niza));
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You can't assign to a function.  You're looking for `set()`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Array is in fact ArrayList, and assuming you want to store the value that is at index `d + 1` in the index `d`, you need

```
temp.set(d, temp.get(d + 1));
```

`temp.get(d)` is not a variable to which you can assign a value. It's an expression returning a value. And you can't assign anything to a value.

Comment: now there's a problem with   n = temp.size;

it says Array.java:134: error: variable temp might not have been initialized
        n= temp.size;

Comment: That's a good thing you get this error: you indeed haven't initialized temp. Do it.

Answer (score 0):

As the other users have said, you have to use the `set()` method to change the value stored at an index of your array.

I think you meant to use an ArrayList. If that is the case, then you should be using `n = temp.size()` instead of `n = temp.size` to get the length of the list, as `size` is a method in the ArrayList class.